# Can't bind HTML form with MVC action

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

MVC beginner here. I got stuck on this issue. I have such view:

```
<form method="post" action="@Url.Action("UserAddRequested", "UsersController")" >        
    First name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" value="">
    <br>
    Last name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" value="">

    <br>
    Age:<br>
    <input type="text" name="age" value="">

    <br>
    Email:<br>
    <input type="text" name="email" value="">

    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="Create" />

</form>
```

Hopefully you understand intention when user clicks create I want to call an action `UserAddRequested` in controller.

This is controller code

```
[HttpPost]
   public ActionResult UserAddRequested()
   {
         return Content("Hi");
   }
```

But when user clicks create button, nothing is displayed :(( Can someone help?

Comment: Did you try changing the type of button to "submit" ? `<input type="submit" value="Create" />`

Comment: try `<input type="submit" value="Create" />`

Comment: @Shyju Now I get an error, after clicking the button, please see below the answer

Comment: @Shyju Is there other way I can specify action instead of URL.Action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add type="submit" to your button and No need to add  UsersController just rename that to Users

```
<form method="post" action="@Url.Action("UserAddRequested", "Users")" >        
    First name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" value="">
    <br>
    Last name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" value="">

    <br>
    Age:<br>
    <input type="text" name="age" value="">

    <br>
    Email:<br>
    <input type="text" name="email" value="">

    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="Create" />

</form>
```

Comment: my god now it works. removing controller helped. so awkward

Comment: what other way is to specify action instead of URL.action?

Comment: Good. You don't need to type controller code will automatically detect it controller.

Comment: You must use Razor Form.

Answer (score 0):

you aren't *submitting* anything in your view.  Instead you are using a plain HTML button.  You need to change the `type` of that button to `type="submit"`.  There shouldn't be any difference in HTML/CSS between `type = "button"` and `type = "submit"`

```
<input type="submit" value="Create" />
```

Comment: Yes but now I get this error when I click the button:  Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /UsersController/UserAddRequested

Comment: @user300400  if the view that you are using corresponds with the controller that holds the *ActionResult* you do not need to put the controller in there. just use the action name

Comment: thanks just other userwas first to suggest removing controller name. I would upvote you if I had rep